# school work delivery list mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
Table students and table of school work delivered

```
Students table
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| id                       |   name                          |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 1                        |   ADAM                          |
| 2                        |   BRIGITTE                      |
| 3                        |   ANNE                          |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+

table student works
+---------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| id_works      |   works                 |   id_student     |
+---------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| 1             |   airplane wing         |   1              |
| 2             |   volcano               |   2              |
| 3             |   law of gravity        |   1              |
| 4             |   airplane wing         |   3              |
| 5             |   law of gravity        |   1              |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
```

How do I make a SELECT for work that returns the **entire** list of students, indicating that the work is delivered? (IMPORTANT: list of all students)

Example

```
LIST FOR WORK **airplane wing**
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
|  ADAM                    |   X                             |
|  BRIGITTE                |                                 |
|  ANNE                    |   X                             |
+--------------------------+--------------------- -----------+
```

I have tried it with LEF JOIN and IF, but it is not the list of all the students without repeating them.

```
SELECT
    s.name ,
    w.work,
    w.resid_id,
    if(w.work  = 'airplane wing', 'X', '') as mark

    FROM  students s
    LEFT JOIN works w
    ON  s.id = w.id_student

    ORDER BY s.name ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a list of all students
And fields `id_works` and `works` will be null for those who didn't complete the work

```
SELECT s.name, w.id_works, w.works

FROM  students s
LEFT JOIN works w
    ON (w.id_student = s.id AND w.works = 'airplane wing')

ORDER BY s.name ASC
```